# C# Get File List of StartMenu Error: UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the files list from my Start menu, but when I use these codes, it throws out this error: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

I am in the administrator mode, and I don't know how can I deal with it.

```
string[] InkFileList = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu), "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I try to add these codes in my app.manifest, but it doesn't work.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet below should help you out.

```
var path = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs";  
var itemsList = new List<string>();  
var startMenuFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f));  
itemsList.AddRange(startMenuFiles);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this path, but the list of shortcuts I get seems to be incomplete. So I want to combine the shortcuts in  "C:\ProgramData\\Microsoft\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs" and "Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu)" to get the complete list of Start Menu applications.

Comment: `Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu` actually points to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` folder for that specific user. So if you're not able to use it via Environment variables, you can maybe try specifying the file path manually (like I did above in my answer).

Comment: Thanks to your reply, I was able to access the path using a string. It seems I still don't know much about Environment variables.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you found this answer helpful, feel free to upvote the answer & mark it as accepted so that it can help others as well. Thanks!